# Accidentally deleted my character with lots of item in a safe

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was playing Terraria and my cousin took my cellphone. It was possible that when he took it he accidentally deleted my most valuable character with lots of items in the safe. Is there any possible way to get my stuff back?

Comment: is this on an apple product or an android?

Answer (score 0):

Hello There and welcome to Arqade!
I had a similar problem on my android device once, sorry to break it to ya but there's no way of getting your stuff back unless you have a back on an SD card or something.
But i'm not sure about apple products for I havent played terraria in one.

Comment: If you're not sure on something, you might want to research more on your answer. Providing something incomplete isn't super helpful.

Comment: I can't say anything on something I haven't really tried sorry. Some of my friends say they also can't retrieve their info in an IOS cloud database because it auto saves everything you do in the game. I can't pass information i haven't tried myself for it might cause confusion.